# xpath to extract all the text in a specific node and return it as one element using scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

So I have this html:

```
<html>
<p>
   This is my first sentence
   <br>
   This sentance should be considered as part of the first one.
   <br>
   And this also
</p>
<p>
   This is the second sentence
</p>
</html>
```

I want to extract the text from the p nodes, all the text in one node should be returned as one element, I am using scrapy shell like this:

```
scrapy shell path/to/file.html
response.xpath('//p/text()').extract()
```

the output I get is:

```
[
'This is my first sentence',
'This sentance should be considered as part of the first one.'
'And this also'
'This is the second sentence'
]
```

the output I want:

```
[
 'This is my first sentence This sentance should be considered as part of the first one And this also'
 'This is the second sentence'
]
```

Any help about how to solve this using xpath expression

Thank you very much :))))

Comment: Could you just join  the list items in the list returned from respose.xpath?  " ".join(x for x in list_returned_from_xpath)

Comment: Actually this is not possible for me, I need to solve it using xpath because I have many p elements and each element has a number of texts that I don't know, and some more reasons also. It would be much better if there is a solution using xpath.

Comment: Scrapy only supports XPath-1.0. But this can AFAIK only be solved with XPath-2.0 or above. So I doubt that you'll find a solution without doing this at the Python level.

Comment: @zx485 Thank you very much, I will then go a level higher like `//p` then I get all the html and clean it to get the final text. Please add your comment as an answer to this question.

Comment: It would be great if you could extend your example XML to include the reason why selecting paragraphs first does not work for you. Maybe someone can come up with a good solution that takes into account those limitations you mention in your comment.

Comment: @Gallaecio I just used the `w3lib.html.remove_tags` function, well it was an easy solution, I tought it would be more complicated that's why I wanted an XPath solution but as this is implemented in XPath-2 then I think there is a need for it? I would say it is just a neat solution:P

Comment: Would you consider providing a response with your approach? I would love to see a simple code sample on how to use `w3lib.html.remove_tags()` to remove undesired tags.

Comment: @Gallaecio I updated the question

Comment: If you've solved your problem, post the solution as an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the issue...

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
two_texts = response.xpath('//p').extract()
two_texts = [remove_tags(text) for text in two_texts]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could have avoided `w3lib` using `' '.join()` as suggested in the comments:

```py
paragraphs = response.css('p')
paragraphs = [' '.join(p.xpath('./text()').getall()) for p in paragraphs]
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it works fine but still needs to clean html tags (+1)